# Typed stream inside a streambuilder in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder

I am using stream who return groupmodel type in a streamBuilder but i am not able to reach the data in the builder.

```
StreamBuilder<GroupModel>(
          stream: groups
              .where('users', arrayContains: firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid)
              .snapshots()
              .map((QuerySnapshot<Object> res) =>
                  GroupModel.fromJson(res as Map<String, dynamic>)),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<GroupModel> snapshot) {
            log(snapshot.data.toString());
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Text(snapshot.data.toString());
            } else {
              return const Text('No data');
            }
          },
        ));
```

If i modify the value in firebase i can see a null output from

```
    log(snapshot.data.toString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to call a `map()` list over a `Stream` which will be `null` at first before getting data from firestore, using that `Stream` directly in `StreamBuilder`, you need to wait for the `QuerySnapshot` to arrive, then act based on its value on the `StreamBuilder` :

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: groups
              .where('users', arrayContains: firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid)
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final userDoc = snapshot.data!.docs.first;
            final data = userDoc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
            final model = GroupModel.fromJson(data);
              return Text("${data}, ${model}");
            } else {
              return const Text('No data');
            }
          },
        ));
```

Comment: Thank you, I trying to build my app though the clean architecture principe is there anyway where i could use my model to pass the data ?

Comment: pass data between screens ? can you clarify for me what you're trying to achieve exactly

Comment: Sorry my question was not clear. 
So first your answer is working thank you but that was just a example for stack overflow.
I am using the data domain presentation pattern and would like to create the stream typed with my group model in my data folder and calling him in my presentation folder